# How to select an element that has no attributes

Tags: javascript

So i have couple of spans within a div and most of them have classes or other attributes.

```
<span class="one" attribute="test"></span>
<span></span> /* This is what i need to select */
<span class="three" attribute="test"></span>
<span class="four" attribute="test"></span>
<span></span>
```

I would like to select the very first span that has no attributes but also make sure that the last span that has no attributes wont be selected.

Also, the element with class `one` will sometimes appear and sometimes wont so i can't select it with a number like:  `[1]`.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: loop though all of them until you find the one that you want.

Comment: What do you want to do with that span? You just want to delete or what else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check to see how many attributes an element has by checking the length of its `attributes` property:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const spanWithNoAttributes = [...div.children]
  .find(span => span.attributes.length === 0);
spanWithNoAttributes.textContent = 'THIS ONE HERE';
```

```html
<div>
<span class="one" attribute="test">one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span class="three" attribute="test">three</span>
<span class="four" attribute="test">four</span>
<span>five</span>
</div>
```

You should also fix up your HTML - end tags should have a slash *before* the tag name, not after.

Comment: That does the trick, i am aware that i misplaced the slashes i was just too lazy to put them on the right spot so i just rolled with it and hoped nobody will notice but here you are. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of spans is the same, and if the span never gets attributes, then you could just use the `nth-child` selector.

With jQuery...

```
$("span:nth-child(2)").blah.blah;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure there are no attributes at all, you'll need to select the elements by tag (or globally) and perform a filter.

```js
var spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span"));

var noattrs = spans.find(s => !s.attributes.length);

alert(noattrs.outerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="one" attribute="test"></span>
<span></span> /* This is what i need to select */
<span class="three" attribute="test">/<span>
<span class="four" attribute="test"></span>
<span></span>
```

However, be aware that there are legacy browsers that may automatically set some attributes in the `.attributes` list, so this may not work in all cases.

---

If you only need to prevent those with a specific attribute or set of attributes, you can use the `:not()` selector with the "has attribute" selector.

```js
var noattr = document.querySelector("span:not([attribute])");

alert(noattr.outerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="one" attribute="test"></span>
<span></span> /* This is what i need to select */
<span class="three" attribute="test">/<span>
<span class="four" attribute="test"></span>
<span></span>
```

If there are other specific ones to prevent, you can add more `:not()` selectors.  `"span:not([attribute]):not([id]):not([class])"`